# Using SSL on slapd

Tags: ssl-certificate, openldap, tls

I am setting up slapd to use SSL on Fedora 14. I have the following in my /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif:

```
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/SSL_CA_Bundle.pem
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.crt
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.key
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2
olcTLSVerifyClient: demand
```

and the following in my /etc/sysconfig/ldap:

```
SLAPD_LDAP=no
SLAPD_LDAPS=yes
```

In my ldap.conf file, I have

```
BASE    dc=mydomain,dc=com
URI ldaps://localhost
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/pki/tls/certs
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

However, when I connect to the localhost, ldapsearch returns the following:

```
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
ldap_create
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
TLS: loaded CA certificate file /etc/pki/tls/certs/978601d0.0 from CA certificate directory /etc/pki/tls/certs.
TLS: loaded CA certificate file /etc/pki/tls/certs/b69d4130.0 from CA certificate directory /etc/pki/tls/certs.
TLS certificate verification: defer
TLS: error: connect - force handshake failure: errno 0 - moznss error -12271
TLS: can't connect: .
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

What do I have incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Check your server logs, but I believe your problem lies with `olcTLSVerifyClient: demand` -- This is **requiring** that your *client* present a certificate to the server to authenticate itself during the handshake, and unless you have a certificate there (which is deemed acceptable by the server) you will not be allowed to connect.

You may also want to peruse [this site](http://www.openldap.org/pub/ksoper/OpenLDAP_TLS.html) (or [this one](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html)) which has details on OpenLDAP & TLS (SSL) -- Your configuration is a bit different than the examples I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want clients to use a cert to identify themselves, you will need to tell the client what cert to use.  man ldap.conf gives TLS_CERT and TLS_KEY